# Angular CLI and loading assets with import.meta.url causing Not allowed to load local resource: error

Tags: angular, webpack

In my JS file I have these assets loaded like

```
const loadingGif3 = new URL('/src/assets/images/loading-3.gif', import.meta.url);
const noImg = new URL(',,/../assets/images/noimage.png', import.meta.url);
```

however I get an error

Not allowed to load local resource: *file url here*

I'm using Angular CLI v14.2.0 so I guess it's using webpack 5 under the hood which recommends to load assets with the import.meta.url way.

Am I missing something blindingly obvious?

Comment: Same problem on 14.2.0

Comment: Same. Any progress?

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that Angular has disabled webpack's bundling of assets referenced with `import.meta.url`, which leads to the default (and quite broken) behaviour of rewriting `import.meta.url` to a `file://` URL on the local filesystem, which is not where the asset will eventually live, obviously.

It appears that you can disable this with `parser.javascript.importMeta` in a custom webpack config.  Make sure you have webpack 5.68.0 or newer.  Here is the relevant flag: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#moduleparserjavascriptimportmeta

This will preserve `import.meta.url` but it won't bundle the asset, so in this case (or if you disabled `parser.javascript.importMeta`), you need to add it to the `assets` section in your `angular.json`.  Likewise, the experimental (for now) `esbuild` support will behave the same way.

EDIT: *Alternately*, you can *re-enable* webpack's default treatment of `new URL(..., import.meta.url)` which is to bundle (and munge the names of, etc) the assets referenced by it.  This is done with this flag: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#moduleparserjavascripturl

Angular's default is somewhere in between - it allows webpack to bundle workers (presumably because people would notice right away if this were broken), but nothing else, including WASM files, which can cause some nasty surprises.

You will have to install `@angular-builders/custom-webpack` and use `@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser` and `@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server` in place of the default ones in your `angular.json`.

Then add a custom webpack config like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    parser: {
      javascript: {
        importMeta: false,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

or, for the second solution,

```js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    parser: {
      javascript: {
        url: true,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

For an explanation of why Angular does this see:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/24617

Also note that you probably have to delete your `.angular` directory before rebuilding for the change to actually take effect.